# Html2canvas does not support svg format file. Html2canvas does not support some css3 properties, such as the transform property

Tags: html2canvas

My company USES the html2canvas screenshot framework, but it does not support SVG format and is not friendly to the new CSS properties, such as transform, and the shape of the ellipse can sometimes be inconsistent with the original image.
There is no new open source framework to support these requirements. There is no framework to replace the html2canvas framework with the functionality of the screenshot.
My English is not good, I use the translation, thank you

Comment: no people know it？

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, but here's the think you should consider:

1. html2canvas is only support this [CSS Property](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/docs/features.md).
2. the developers themselves say "It's not suitable for production".

But if you still want to use it, you can try to make work around by changing the CSS before render and change it back after render.

Also for the SVG issue, you can use plugin [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg), replace the svg with the canvas that `canvg` provide before render.

But it's still unstable, the image sometime is off the image.

i suggest to use server side capture with phantomjs, here's the example for that:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

it's quite fast i would say.

Hope it could help.